# When One Object Rotates on X Axis, Another Object Rotates on Z Axis (Constrains)

Tags: constraints

**When this circle object rotates on the X axis, I want the cylinder object to rotate along the Z axis.**

**I'm pretty sure this can be done with the copy rotation constraint, because I did it once before, but I can't reproduce the effect for some reason.**

[image]

**Here is the Blender file that is not working:**

[image]

**For some reason I did this once before and it worked, but I can't reproduce it. Here is the working file:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to transfer a rotation from one axis to another, you need to use the transformation constraint. That way, you can map the transformations from one object to another one. You can as well change the source axis of the transfered transformations.

In your case, you want to read the X rotation transforms of the circle and convert them into rotations on the Z axis for the object, so you'll have to use these parameters :

[image]

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your help!